# People who have received less in dunya would they receive more in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, akhirah, world

Many muslims they had successful and happy life in this world, maybe they had wealth or became a famous or became a great scholar or became a leader or had a good spouse and children etc whatever maybe you can say they had it good.  While others didn't achieve much or nothing even if they tried hard for successes so you can say they had it less in this world would they receive more in Jannah because they had less in dunya? Please answer with evidence from Quran and hadith if you can.